# MS SQL Execute multiple updates based on a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the problem that I found out how to fix the database the only problem is that I have to insert the CaseNumber for one execution everytime.

In C# I would use somekind of string list for the broken records is there something in MS SQL.

My Code so far I implemented a variable CaseNumber. I have a table with a lot of Casenumber records that are broken. Is there a way to execute this for every Casenumber of a different table.

Like: 
1. Take the first casenumber and run this script.
2. Than take the second one and run this script again until every casenumber was fixed.

Thx in advance for any idea.

```
GO
DECLARE @CaseNumber VARCHAR(50)
SET @CaseNumber = '25615'
print 'Start fixing broken records.' 
print 'Fixing FIELD2'

UPDATE t
    SET t.FIELD2 = ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 FIELD2 
                     FROM {myTable} t2
                     WHERE IDFIELD = @CaseNumber
                     AND FIELD2 IS NOT NULL )
FROM {myTable} t
WHERE FIELD2 IS NULL 
  AND IDFIELD = @CaseNumber
</Code>
```

Comment: Your script has some logical flaws. Distinct and top 1? By definition a single row is always distinct. But in your case you have top 1 but there is no order by so you don't know which row you will get. You could most likely use a table valued parameter here and update a whole group in a single pass.

Comment: Update a whole group with a single pass ?

Comment: A single update statement that receives a table valued parameter. Then you join to it. You do not want to do this RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: Is the myTable in the subquery a different table than the myTable in the main query?  I can't tell

Comment: The {myTable} is the same. The table with the casenumbers looks like ID=0 and a value = 123

Comment: An update statement that receives a table valued parameter ?

Comment: So you are wanting to update field2 where it is blank with a different field2 where not blank but the case number is the same in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple different options...

```
-- This verion will just "fix" everything that can be fixed.
UPDATE mt1 SET 
    mt1.FIELD2 = mtx.FIELD2                        
FROM
    dbo.myTable mt1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            mt2.FIELD2
        FROM
            dbo.myTable mt2
        WHERE 
            mt1.IDFIELD = mt2.IDFIELD 
            AND mt2.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
        ) mtx
WHERE 
    mt1.FIELD2 IS NULL;
```

And if, for whatever reason, you don't want to fix the entire table all in one go. You can restrain to to just those you specify...

```
-- This version will works off the same principal but limits itself to only those values in the @CaseNumCSV parameter.
DECLARE @CaseNumCSV VARCHAR(8000) = '25615,25616,25617,25618,25619';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CaseNum', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #CaseNum; END;

CREATE TABLE #CaseNum (
    CaseNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CaseNumber)
        WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON) -- just in case the same CaseNumber is in the string multiple times.
    );
INSERT #CaseNum(CaseNumber)
SELECT 
    CaseNumber = dsk.Item
FROM
    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@CaseNumCSV, ',') dsk;
    -- a copy of DelimitedSplit8K can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

UPDATE mt1 SET 
    mt1.FIELD2 = mtx.FIELD2
FROM
    #CaseNum cn
    JOIN dbo.myTable mt1
        ON cn.CaseNumber = mt1.IDFIELD
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP (1)
            mt2.FIELD2
        FROM
            dbo.myTable mt2
        WHERE 
            mt1.IDFIELD = mt2.IDFIELD 
            AND mt2.FIELD2 IS NOT NULL
        ) mtx
WHERE 
    mt1.FIELD2 IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jason I will try it and give you response.